# Perl + Catalyst hosting only possible on a (pricey) VPS?

Tags: vps, hosting, perl, cisco-catalyst

I'm about to set up a website with a Wiki and was looking at [MojoMojo](http://mojomojo.org/) as a more user friendly alternative to MediaWiki.

The problem however is that it runs on Perl and Catalyst framework, for which it seems that I have to go for a VPS solution, which is much more expensive than just getting a bog standard shared PHP host.

Do you know if there's any hosting service where I could get this running for something more reasonable than $20 / month (which is the cheapest Linode plan), but without sacrificing quality?

I don't expect huge traffic on the website, but of course it would be good to have generous bandwidth allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to go through a VPS solution for Catalyst; I'm running my Catalyst apps in FastCGI mode on shared hosting with Dreamhost, and although it's not the most convenient environment for development (reinitializing the fastcgi processes is a hassle compared with a dedicated-process environment), it should work just fine for deploying a shipped product. The Catalyst wiki provides a [list of Catalyst-friendly hosting providers](http://wiki.catalystframework.org/wiki/hosting), and Dreamhost's wiki contains [a tutorial on getting Catalyst up and running](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Catalyst). I'm a huge advocate of Catalyst as a framework, and MojoMojo's a good example of what's possible with it; I hope this helps you get it working!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, really appreciated! I tried in the meanwhile to set things up on a local Ubuntu server virtual machine and got a bit lost in thousands of lines of output and MojoMojo not working in the end :) Will try again at some point, still prefer MojoMojo to MediaWiki!